# Sql Statement for a particular xpath

Tags: xpath-2.0, xquery-sql

I have a XPath statement that works well on my xml.

```
//PaymentProperty[Name='PaymentReference']/StoredStringValue
```

When I store this xml in mytable.xmlField, is there a way to get this value from SQL?
I tried

```
select  x.xml.query('//PaymentProperty[@Name=PaymentReference]/StoredStringValue') from (select cast(xmlField as xml) as xml from mytable
```

But I guess XQuery likes different syntax? It is quite a dynamic xml so all I need to know is if there is Value of "PaymentReference" anywhere in the parentNode PaymentProperty against the tag  then get the value against the tag StoredStringValue. Is there anyway to achieve this from SQL?

Thanks for all the help